# Don't get a Process object when launch a Browser with Process.Start()

Tags: vb.net, process, wait

Windows 7 (64 bits); VB in VS2008 (WOW); .NET 3.51

```
 Dim MyProcess As New System.Diagnostics.Process()

 MyProcess.StartInfo.FileName = My.Resources.TARGET
 MyProcess.Start() 'everything is copacetic to here
 MyProcess.WaitForExit 'likewise if TARGET is a text file name,
                       'but not for URLs
```

When the TARGET is a URL, **Start** correctly launches the default browser 
(the UI of which does exactly what is expected), but **WaitForExit** throws
this exception:

[image]

```
 MyProcess.Close()  'fine for Notepad, never arrives here if IE or Firefox.
```

I haven't tested this much: I will check out other methods/properties of Process and report back.  The code works fine with Notepad (and I gather from SO and other sites, with many other EXEs) and fails with both Firefox and IE. Why?

Ideas?  Am I barking up the wrong tree?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting StartInfo.FileName  to iexplore.exe and start info arguments to the URL.

Comment: I modified my code to explicitly create and set StartInfo for MyProcess and passed two parameters:  FileName and Arguments, and everything seems to work fine.  Many thanks.  I earlier had (related?) problems with the return's WaitForExit and HasExited, but the problems have gone away.  Go figure.  I don't like having to call out the browser by name, but there doesn't seem to be any alternative.